# Node.js equivalent of Yarn command

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg, pm2

I'm going through [js-stack-from-scratch](https://github.com/verekia/js-stack-from-scratch) using Node, not Yarn.

In the [PM2 (Process Manager) section](https://github.com/verekia/js-stack-from-scratch/blob/master/tutorial/03-express-nodemon-pm2.md#pm2) we are to add
`"prod:build": "rimraf lib && babel src -d lib --ignore .test.js"`
to the `"scripts"` section of package.json, and then to run `yarn prod:build`.
I need the Node equivalent please.

(I got around the previous Nodemon section by substituting `dev:start` for `dev-start` but this doesn't work for `prod:build`, presumably because this time it's on the command line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm run prod:build` should do the trick.

Comment: Did you mean `npm run prod:build`, because this works?

Comment: Yes! :) Sorry, typo.